# Dynamic TopN Selection problem while selecting another filter slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, greatest-n-per-group, slicers

In Power BI, I have created a dynamic TopN visual where we can see **top 3 to top 10** teams in terms of total goals scored in FIFA World Cups. I am using a **parameter** called **Top Rankings** for TopN selection. However, the TopN selection does not work when I am selecting another slicer **Year**. When I am selecting the year slicer, the visual shows close to 10 teams although I have selected only 4 teams in the slicer parameter. I am providing the dax measure, table which is used to create the measure and the visual as well.

Dax -

```
# TopN Teams by Goal Scored = 
VAR ranking = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(All_WC_matches[Teams]), [Overall Scored],,DESC,Dense)
Return
IF(
    ranking <= 'Top Rankings'[Top Rankings Value],
    [Overall Scored]
)
```

Only TopN slicer selected

[image: Only TopN slicer selected]

Both TopN and Year slicers selected

[image: Both TopN and Year slicer selected]

Table used for the measure

[image: Table used for the measure]

This is the link to my power bi report
https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZWRkNjRkZmQtZGM5Ny00OTQyLTlmYjgtYzNhZGUxYTFkMTQ2IiwidCI6IjllMmY0M2FmLTExYzMtNGQ5NC1iYTVlLTc3Y2QwNzJlOWMwYiJ9

Link to my Power BI file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/194jBF5M8KMLSAcfvzDjeotftdOahtnZG/view?usp=sharing

I am expecting that TopN selection will be affected by other slicers. However, the number of top teams selected will remain unchanged.

Comment: We need to see your data model. Can you share the .pbix?

Comment: Of course sir. I am attaching the file. @DavidBacci

Comment: @DavidBacci, I have added a Google Drive link. You can access the file there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ranking is working as designed. i.e.

Selecting top 3 and 1930 returns 7 results as you have 5 teams all scoring 7 goals. Look at the table below for an explanation.

[image]

Comment: Okay, sir. Thank you for the clarification. Now, I am able to do rectification in my report by restricting those results to 5 top values.

Comment: Sir, I don't know the procedure.